# Codimension of analytic linear subspaces in Polish vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

Let $A$ be a linear analytic subspace of a Polish vector space $X$.
Using Piccard-Pettis Theorem, it is easy to prove that $A$ has uncountable codimension in $X$. If $A$ is of type $F_\sigma$, then applying Mycielski-Kuratowski Theorem, it is possible to prove more: that the codimension of $A$ in $X$ is equal to $\mathfrak c$. Is this fact still true for any  analytic linear subspace?

> **Problem.** Let $A$ be a proper dense linear analytic subspace of a Polish vector space $X$.
> Is the codimension of $A$ in $X$ equal to $\mathfrak c$?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti To have uncountable index does not imply to have uncountable codimension: just look at the line in the plane. And under MA every separable Banach space contains a meager subspace of codimension 1 (and of course of uncountable index).

Comment: Ah I see now, I forgot what codimension means